# how many images can add in css3 background-image?

Tags: css, animation

Im trying to add multiple backgrounds in css background-image to create a small snow animation. I have 6 images:

> snow_big, snow_medium, snow_small, snow_man, tree1 and tree2

if is use only 4 images for animation my animation works perfectly but when i add more images. the snow animation stop working its only animate left to right side but not top to bottom or maybe stop sometimes. This happens **only in IE10** but other browsers its working i dont know i check the sequence but it good.
here is the css code im using:

```
.xmas_theme_animation {
    background-color:navy;
    height:115px;
    width:345px;
    background-image: url('../images/snow_big.png')
    ,url('../images/snow_medium.png')
    ,url('../images/snow_small.png')
    ,url('../images/snow1_snowman.png')
    ,url('../images/tree1.png')
    ,url('../images/tree2.png');
    background-repeat: repeat, repeat, repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 6% bottom, 20% bottom, 40% bottom;    
    animation: snowfall 10s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes snowfall {
    from {background-position: 0 -340px, 0 -172.5px, 0 0px, 6% bottom, 20% bottom, 40% bottom;  }
    to {background-position: 0 345px, 661px 172.5px, 0 345px, 6% bottom, 20% bottom, 40% bottom;}
}
```

so is there any limitation for using multiple backgrounds in css??
Thanks

Comment: As a workaround, you can set images on pseudo elements before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use percentage(%) value for background-position on @keyframes. Use pixel(px) value instead. 
When you use percentage, the animation stops working on IE while it stills works on other browsers. I experimented this on jsfiddle on both IE and chrome. Have a look. All 6 images are animating, even on IE. http://jsfiddle.net/qLtxr/

```
.xmas_theme_animation {
        background-color:navy;
        width:800px;
        height: 500px;
        background-image: url('http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/at-twitter_reasonably_small.png'),
        url('http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/at-twitter_reasonably_small.png'),
        url('http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/at-twitter_reasonably_small.png'),
        url('http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/at-twitter_reasonably_small.png'),
        url('http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/at-twitter_reasonably_small.png'),
        url('http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/at-twitter_reasonably_small.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 6% bottom, 20% bottom, 40% bottom;  
        -webkit-animation: snowfall 10s  linear infinite;
        animation: snowfall 10s  linear infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes snowfall {
      from {background-position:0 -340px, 0 -172px, 0 0px, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;  }
      to {background-position: 0 345px, 661px 172px, 0 345px, 60px 400px, 200px 100px, 400px 150px;}
    }

    @keyframes snowfall {
      from {background-position: 0 -340px, 0 -172px, 0 0px, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;  }
      to {background-position: 0 345px, 661px 172px, 0 345px, 60px 400px, 200px 100px, 400px 150px;}
    }
```

Comment: Yes you right it's work. I change the percent to pixels then its working..... Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3C Specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#background-image), there is no limit of multiple background images.

However, more images cost more loading time. Are you sure you want to do so?

On the other hand, IE9+ supports multiple background images. Is your page using compatibility mode?

Comment: then why its not working in IE10, when i add one more image in there